# Unity Game - Notifications can't be opened in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I recently published my Android game using Unity. I've used the Unity native notification library to send some notifications to my users. But when I checked my analytics, 60% of my users are getting this error.

How can I fix this?

> AndroidJavaException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to determine
> Activity to be opened when tapping notification
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to determine Activity to be opened
> when tapping notification
> com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationManager.initialize(UnityNotificationManager.java:118)
> com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationManager.getNotificationManagerImpl(UnityNotificationManager.java:141)
> com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
> com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.-$$Nest$mnativeRender(Unknown Source:0)
> com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$C$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source:122)
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
> com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$C.run(Unknown Source:24)
> UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () (at
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
> UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr
> clazz, System.IntPtr methodID, System.Span`1[T] args) (at
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
> UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._CallStatic[ReturnType] (System.IntPtr
> methodID, System.Object[] args) (at
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
> Unity.Notifications.Android.AndroidNotificationCenter.Initialize ()
> (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
> MNotif.registerUnityNotif ()
> (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
> MNotif.Start () (at
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)

Seems like my app isn't being opened by clicking on the notification. Why? I have no clue. But default activity to be opened by Unity Notification is:

- com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity